# Can the Staph streak method be used for culturing Neisseria on blood agar?

Tags: microbiology, cell-culture

What I learned in class:
Normally chocolate agar is needed to grow *Haemophilus* and *Neisseria*. The Staph streak technique can be used for culturing *Haemophilus* on blood agar by allowing the Staph to hemolyze the blood so *Haemophilus* can grow around it.

My question:
Is there a reason this method couldn't be used for *Neisseria* as well?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your species of Neisseria.

*N. meningitidis* grows on BAP (Blood Agar Plate), with colonies being grey and unpigmented on  appearing round, smooth, moist, glistening, and convex, with a clearly defined edge

You can read more about that [here](http://www.cdc.gov/meningitis/lab-manual/chpt07-id-characterization-nm.html).

[image]

*N. gonorrhoeae* is known not to grow on BAP.
More on that [here](http://www.microbiologyinpictures.com/neisseria%20gonorrhoeae.html).